# java.lang.NullPointerException and ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, actionlistener, resultset

This is my first post so please be patient. I am working on a java project and that connects to a sql database. What I am currently trying to do is when I click a button, will display the name of the item and the price of the item with the specified ID in the text area from my database. However, when I click the button an error such as this appears:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at OrderFrame.waterButtonActionPerformed(OrderFrame.java:494)
at OrderFrame.access$000(OrderFrame.java:11)
```

Here is the code for my waterButtonActionPerformed:

```
private void waterButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
// TODO add your handling code here:
    try{

    String query;
    query = "SELECT itemName, itemPrice FROM item WHERE itemID = '11111'";
    String itemName = " ",itemPrice =" ";  

      ***ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);***

       if(rs != null){
        while(rs.next())
        { 
         itemName = rs.getString(1);
         itemPrice = rs.getString(2);
        }
       orderTextArea.setText(itemName);
       orderTextArea.setText(itemPrice);
       }
         } catch (SQLException ex) {}
}
```

The line 494 is the one with the declaration of the ResultSet. I am am hoping someone can help me fix this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is variable `st`? Most likely, you are not initializing it.

Comment: I'm assuming that your `st` reference isn't initialized.

Comment: I'm surprised you actually got this far without knowing what causes a nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the handler, like this:

```
waterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
// TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
       Statement st = connectionObject.createStatement();

       // might want to use placeholders here as well
       String query= "SELECT itemName, itemPrice FROM item WHERE itemID = '11111'"; 
       String itemName = " ",itemPrice =" ";  

       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

       if(rs != null){
         do { 
           itemName = rs.getString(1);
           itemPrice = rs.getString(2);
        } while (rs.next());
        orderTextArea.setText(itemName);
        orderTextArea.setText(itemPrice);
        }
      } catch (SQLException ex) { 
         System.err.println(new java.util.Date()+" : "+ex.getMessage(); 
      }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`st` is `null`. You need something like

```
con.prepareStatement(query);
```

Where `con` is your connection to the SQL database. You don't show how you connect to the database here. [Here's a good tutorial on how to do that.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like st is null. Your example doesn't show where st is declared, much less initialized.

You probably need to create a Statement from your query (which is just a string)

Answer (score 1):

It look like that st is null .please check your st otherwise write the code

```
conn.prepareStatement(query)
```